# Icon Style has different results than Icon Class

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am trying to use the Font-Awesome icons in my site.

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="some-link"><center><h2><i class = "fa fa-hdd-o" style = "color:black;vertical-align:middle;font-size:40px"></i> Mining Rig Building Service</h2></center></a>
```

This is how I want it to look, which is also how it looks with the element-styling:

[image: Original Image with Element-Styling]

This has different results than if I use:

```
<a href="some-link"><center><h2><i class = "fa fa-hdd-o icon-40" style = "color:black;"></i> Mining Rig Building Service</h2></center></a>
```

With this in my stylesheet:

```
.icon-40 {
    font-size: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    }
```

The icon isn't aligned correctly here:

[image: New version with class-styling]

I get the same result (with the misaligned icon) if I set the class to `icon-40 fa fa-hdd-o` instead of `fa fa-hdd-o icon-40`.

How can I align this icon? I want to use the class instead of the direct element-styling because I will have a lot of similar icons, and I don't want to use element-styling for all of them.

Comment: Something like this? [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/5C4rL/)

Comment: Also the `<center>` element has been deprecated and should no longer be used.

Comment: @Ruddy sort of, except the icon is part of a font, not an image :/. Also, I want to be able to position it wherever I want without setting an explicit left/right location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems, it looks like your example, inline - http://jsfiddle.net/G29Tw/

```
<a href="some-link"><center><h2><i class = "fa fa-hdd-o" style = "color:black;vertical-align:middle;font-size:40px"></i> Mining Rig Building Service</h2></center></a>
```

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. I actually fixed it by renaming the class `font-40` to another name. In the cPanel editor for my stylesheet, `icon` was highlighted in `icon-40`, so it might have been another class that it was clashing with.